# Let $v,g \in L^{p}(a,b)$ such that $v(x)-v(y)=\int^x_yg(t)dt$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, continuity, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

This exercise is about the continuity of functions in Sobolev spaces in dimension one.

Let $v \in L^{p}(a,b)$ and $g \in L^{p}(a,b)$ such that $v(x)-v(y)=\int^x_yg(t)dt$ and this $\forall x,y \in (a,b)$

Show that $v \in W^{1,p}$ and that $v'=g$ in the sense of distributions.

So far I can only prove that $v$ is continuous using Holder's identity, but I don't know how to proceed.

Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: If I were you, I'd start by writing out what "$v'=g$ in the sense of distributions" means.  This would give you some direction on what you need to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c \in (a, b)$. We can take
$$v(x) = \int_c^x g(t)dt.$$
We have, for $\varphi \in C^\infty_0$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b v \varphi' &= \int_a^b \left(\int_c^x g(t)dt\right) \varphi'(x)dx \\
&= -\int_a^c dx\int_x^cg(t)\varphi'(x)dt + \int_c^b dx\int_c^x g(t)\varphi'(x)dt\\
&= -\int_a^c g(t)dt\int_a^t\varphi'(x)dx + \int_c^b g(t)dt\int_t^b \varphi'(x)dx\\
&= -\int_a^b g(t)\varphi(t)dt
\end{align}
and you deduce the desired result. The third equality comes from Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was about to do this but the order of the questions threw me off. I thought I was supposed to show that $ v \in L^p(a,b)$ before showing the integral. Or it doesn't matter ?

Comment: @tareqath in your original post, $v\in L^p(a,b)$ is an assumption.

Comment: The part $v \in L^p(a, b)$ is kind of straigtforward, just apply Jensen's inequality for example.

Comment: @Falcon I'm really sorry, I meant $v \in W^{1,p}$. I can't edit it. My concern is the order of the questions, showing that $v \in W^{1,p}$ directly instead of deducing it from $v'=g$. Or is the order irrelevant ?

Comment: @Surb I'm really sorry, I meant $v \in W^{1,p}$